# How to convert a data matrix (x's and nulls) into relational rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I encountered a problem, where I need to convert a data matrix (with X's and empty cells) into some kind of a list; I have already seen similar questions in here, but I was unable to apply it for my data to work.

This is the matrix I have:

```
        | A | B | ... | N |
-------------------------------
  1     | x |   | ... | x |
  2     |   | x | ... |   |
  .       .   .   ...   .
  .       .   .   ...   .
  .       .   .   ...   .
  N     | x | x | ... |   |
```

The columns and rows number can vary.

I want the output table to be like that:

```
| column1 |  column2 |
-------------------------------
    1           A 
    1           N 
    2           B 
    .           .
    .           .
    .           .
    N           A 
    N           B
```

I think it is understandable :) Any help would be appreciated :)

Here is the real data I use:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SlYKMrZy5cyQ7sljTvmiwu6XkIDN_WILDhEM4cWyYnk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Michal,
i have come up with a fairly robust method for this "retabulation" problem. Could you make the sheet editable so that I can demonstrate it there?

Comment: ok, changed it to editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(Sheet1!B3:EM<>"", "♠"&Sheet1!A3:A&"♦"&Sheet1!B2:2&"♦", ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"))
```

[image]

Comment: exactly when I wanted :) thank you :) do you also know the method to get the opposite? having the output list, to get the first table (with x's)?

Comment: the opposite would be achieved with pivoting in Query. something like: `=QUERY(F:G, "select F,count(F) where F is not null group by F pivot G")`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Player 0 already has something working.  The query header smush is indeed all powerful.  Here is another way to do this kinds of problems with a VLOOKUP.  It's more complicated in some ways, but a little less magic :)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A3:A)*COLUMNS(Sheet1!B2:2),1,0)/COLUMNS(Sheet1!B2:2)+3,{ROW(Sheet1!A3:A),Sheet1!A3:A,IF(OFFSET(Sheet1!B3,,,ROWS(Sheet1!A3:A),COLUMNS(Sheet1!B2:2))="x",Sheet1!B2:2,)},MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A3:A)*COLUMNS(Sheet1!B2:2),1,0),COLUMNS(Sheet1!B2:2))*{0,1}+{2,3}),"where Col2 is not null",0))
```

I've left it in a tab on your sheet called MK.Help